# CSS style not affecting child elements (buttons)

Tags: html, css

Right now if i add inactiveLink class to `<a>` it also affects buttons inside. They cant be clicked anymore. Do i have to make another style `activeLink` that turns those features back on or is there a way to only affect `<a>` element without affecting buttons inside?

If there is no other way, what are default `cursor` and `pointer-events` for Buttons?

**HTML**

```
<a class="text-body selectable-element inactiveLink">
    [...]
    <button>Click</button>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a.inactiveLink {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: button inside link is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>While the other answer will work</s>  (it was deleted as I was typing this), the real question is: If you want the anchor deactivated, should an active button really go inside it?

As the site/app scales, will other developers know what that class does? I think the CSS is fine the way it is, but the HTML could be moved around so those active elements exist outside the inactive anchor (perhaps in a shared parent element). Food for thought!

If you just want the quick fix, add the class "always-active" to the button, and add the following CSS:

```
.always-active {
    cursor: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```css
a.inactiveLink {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
button.always-active {
    pointer-events: auto;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<a class="text-body selectable-element inactiveLink">
    [...]
    <button class="always-active" onClick="alert('it works')">Click</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Its actually ASP.NET application and i show list of elements where every element is clickable, thats why `<a>`. I use this list also on other page where i don't want them to be clickable and i have buttons instead (when its clickable, buttons are not present)

Comment: What do you use for HTML templating? (ie, Razor MVC?)

Comment: I tried with cursor and pointer-events on `auto` but then when i click button its like i click `<a>`. If it comes to moving HTML its rather tricky. i want whole block to be clickable and if its not clickable i want to have buttons inside that block. Cant really move it.

@UP: Razor MVC

Comment: Razor MVC and i use bootstrap 4 `card` element which is wrapped in this `<a>` so whole card is clickable. And i want those buttons inside card aswell.

Comment: I added a code snippet to demonstrate it working. I also tested on bootstrap 4 and it works. Perhaps there's something additional blocking the click?

Comment: It is showing "it works" if i add `onClick` but it redirects me to page that `<a>` directs to.

Comment: use event.preventDefault() in your event handler. But again, the better fix is fixing the template.